# array.filter paramter works only if wrapped around {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to JavaScript and Redux. I am trying to filter an array based on id in one of the reducers in Redux, it does not work if I only pass id to the callback function, but it works if the id is wrapped around {id}.

```
//Default store
const defaultState = {
  articles: [],
  filtercriteria: {}
};

//Reducer
const articlesReducer = (state = defaultState.articles, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
      return [...state, action.article];
    case "REMOVE":
      //return state.filter(id => id !== action.id); //**DOES NOT WORK**
      return state.filter(({id}) => id !== action.id); // **WORKS**
    default:
      return state;
  }
  return state;
};

//Action Creator and Action
const remove = id => {
  return {
    type: "REMOVE",
    id
  };
};

//Action Dispatch
const addActionObject = store.dispatch(add());
store.dispatch(remove(addActionObject.article.id));
```

Comment: `({id})` extracts the "id" property value from each object in the `state` array. Without `{ }`, "id" would be the entire object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well because you are using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

If you didn't use destructuring you would use the function like so:

```
state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.id);
```

But you can use destructuring to assign the existing property "id" to a distinct variable

```
state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work without the brackets just do this:

```
return state.filter(obj => obj.id !== action.id);
```

The comments above from Pointy gave the rest of the answer. 
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Pointy is completely right. There is a place for the object destructuring. The thing is you are filtering an array of objects (articles). Filter gets a predicate function which is the first argument is element of array.

To make a shorter version you can use object destructuring. Also, you could simply write like this `...filter(article => article.id !== action.id);`

Here you can read a bit more about [object destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring). And here a documentation for [array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

You're settings state to be equal to articles, which is an array of objects. So when you write {id}, you're actually destructuring the object being passed in and then storing its id in the id variable. If you don't want to wrap it in curly braces, you can do:

```
return state.filter((article) => article.id !== action.id);
```